# What do extra block variables in Ruby built-in iterators do?

Tags: ruby

Say if you were using the built-in iterator `.each` method on a range:

```
(0..3).each do |x,y,z,a,b,c|
end
```

I know that x is the actual item in the collection, but what does defining additional block variables (`y,z,a,b,c`) to the block actually do? Do they represent something?

Comment: I forget who told me this so I can give credit to them, but blocks are like procs in that they don't check the number of arguments, whereas lambas are like methods in that they do.

Comment: An enumerator is created:  `enum = (0..3).each #=> #<Enumerator: 0..3:each>`. Then the first element of the enumerator is generated and passed to the block: `n = enum.next #=> 0`. Lastly, the block variables are set equal to the element passed to the block and values are assigned to the former using *disambiguation*: `x,y,z = n;  x #=> 0; y #=> nil; z #=> nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method does not give values, then the additional variables will be nil.
When running :

```
(0..3).each do |x,y|
    puts x.class.to_s() + ' ' + y.class.to_s()
end
```

It outputs :

```
Integer NilClass
Integer NilClass
Integer NilClass
Integer NilClass
```

It all depends on what the method sends :

```
def myBlockCaller
    yield 1, 2, 3
    yield 'a', '5'
    yield true
    yield nil, 1
end

myBlockCaller do |x, y, z|
    puts x.class.to_s() + ', ' + y.class.to_s() + ', ' + z.class.to_s()
end
```

Shows :

```
Integer, Integer, Integer
String, String, NilClass
TrueClass, NilClass, NilClass
NilClass, Integer, NilClass
```

Answer (score 2):

They don't "do" anything. If you try it you will see they are nil.

```
(0..3).each do |x,y,z,a,b,c|
  puts x.inspect
  puts y.inspect
  puts z.inspect
  puts a.inspect
  puts b.inspect
  puts c.inspect
end

1
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
2
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
3
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
```

Some iterators use more than one variable like `each_with_index`:

```
(1..3).each_with_index do |n,i|
```

`n` will hold the range item and i is it's index, i.e. 0,1,2

Or in a hash like:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.each do |k,v|
  puts k
  puts v
end

a:
1
b:
2
c:
3
```

Comment: Sometimes methods pay attention to the "arity" of your blocks, sometimes they just don't care. In this case `each` doesn't care.

Comment: `Hash#each` is an interesting example. It may _seem_ it yields two arguments to the block, but in reality it doesn't. It yields __one__ argument, the array `[k, v]`, which is then "deconstructed", in the same way as when you do, say, `x, y = [1, 2]`.

Comment: @tadman are you sure? I always understood that methods do care about the arity of their arguments, blocks don't.

Comment: @steenslag Methods do care, blocks might depending on how they're declared. Sometimes methods inspect the block's arity and behave differently, sometimes they always call the same way regardless and it's your responsibility to declare the right number of variables. Methods can also "not care" by doing `*args` and such where they'll take whatever they're given.